# Pivot on multiple columns in alasql

Tags: sql, alasql

I am new to Alasql, I wonder how can I create a PIVOT and show two aggregation. In below example how can I show AVG of values and SUM of price for each name and security. Also how can I give alias name for each aggregation i.e.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/agershun/alasql/develop/dist/alasql.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <xmp id="output"></xmp>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
    var data = [
        { security: 'Preferred Stock',  name: 'Robert',    value: 5,   price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-3' },
        { security: 'Preferred Stock',  name: 'Robert',    value: 5,   price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-5' },
        { security: 'Common Stock',     name: 'Bert',      value: 20,  price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-6' },
        { security: 'Preferred Stock',  name: 'Elizabeth', value: 10,  price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-6' },
        { security: 'Common Stock',     name: 'Robert',    value: 20,  price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-9' },
        { security: 'Preferred Stock',  name: 'Bert',      value: 20,  price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-11' },
        { security: 'Preferred Stock',  name: 'Robert',    value: 5,   price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-12' },
        { security: 'Preferred Stock',  name: 'Robert',    value: 15,  price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-12' },
        { security: 'Options',          name: 'Bert',      value: 10,  price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-13' },
        { security: 'Preferred Stock',  name: 'Robert',    value: 5,   price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-14' },
        { security: 'Options',          name: 'Robert',    value: 15,  price:10 ,  date: '2014-1-17' }
    ];

    var res = alasql('SELECT name, "Series1" AS SeriesName, security, [value] \
                FROM ?  PIVOT (AVG([value]) FOR security)',[data]);

    print( res );                   

    var res1 = alasql('SELECT name, "Series2" AS SeriesName, security, price \
                FROM ?  PIVOT (SUM([price]) FOR security)',[data]);     
    print( res1 );

    function print(x){
        document.getElementById('output').textContent += JSON.stringify(x,  null, '\t')+"\n";
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

With above code I am getting below result.

```
[{
        "name": "Robert",
        "SeriesName": "Series1",
        "Preferred Stock": 7,
        "Common Stock": 20,
        "Options": 15
    },
    {
        "name": "Bert",
        "SeriesName": "Series1",
        "Common Stock": 20,
        "Preferred Stock": 20,
        "Options": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Elizabeth",
        "SeriesName": "Series1",
        "Preferred Stock": 10
    }
]
[{
        "name": "Robert",
        "SeriesName": "Series2",
        "Preferred Stock": 50,
        "Common Stock": 10,
        "Options": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Bert",
        "SeriesName": "Series2",
        "Common Stock": 10,
        "Preferred Stock": 10,
        "Options": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Elizabeth",
        "SeriesName": "Series2",
        "Preferred Stock": 10
    }
]
```

How to get below result. Thanks in advance

```
[{
        "name": "Robert",
        "Series1 - Preferred Stock": 7,
        "Series1 - Common Stock": 20,
        "Series1 - Options": 15 "Series2 - Preferred Stock": 50,
        "Series2 - Common Stock": 10,
        "Series2 - Options": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Bert",
        "Series1 - Common Stock": 20,
        "Series1 - Preferred Stock": 20,
        "Series1 - Options": 10 "Series2 - Common Stock": 10,
        "Series2 - Preferred Stock": 10,
        "Series2 - Options": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Elizabeth",
        "Series1 - Preferred Stock": 10 "Series2 - Preferred Stock": 10
    }
]
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged `mysql`? `alasql` doesn't use the MySQL database.

Comment: I have removed mysql tag

Answer (score 3):

To append "Series name" you can modify your sql query like this.

```
SELECT name, ("Series1" + security) AS security, [value] \
                    FROM ?  PIVOT (AVG([value]) FOR security)
```

You can check output here..

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/jit_mehta023/qzdfrg0x/1/
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how I can combine result from two json.

Comment: For me, very helpful especially with the working example. Thanks!